# basic intuition of fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

i have taken a course in introductory algebraic topology.i am stuck on the basic informations of a space provided by fundamental groups of the space.

I know that,by fundamental group of space based at a point,we mean homotopy class of a loop based at that point that forms a group under operation of multiplication of the loops based at that point.but what sort of geometric intuitions of the space can be drawn by constructing such a group??how can one link the geometric idea with the definition of fundamental groups...if possible,recommend some basic references which have a geometrically motivated viewpoint of fundamental groups.

Comment: What exactly do you have in mind? It's loops in a topological space modulo homotopy; that's a very geometric idea to begin with. Any book (e.g., Hatcher's) on introductory algebraic topology should give you a bunch of motivations and applications of the fundamental almost immediately after defining it.

Comment: I have felt for 50 years or so that the more intuitive and more powerful approach is via the fundamental groupoid on a set of base points, and this may be found in English only in my book "Topology and Groupoids" http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html, first (differently titled) edition 1968.  For example, the basic Seifert-van Kampen theorem then allows the computation of the fundamental group of the circle, and much more. Also I allow paths as maps $[0,r] \to X$ for $r \geqslant 0$, which saves bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is about intuition, and a good way to build that is based on examples. You already know the definition of fundamental group $\pi_1$ in terms of loops that start and finish at a given point. This will allow you to see that $\pi_1$ for the plane of any subdomain of the plane is the identity.

Next example would be a circunference $S^1$, or a plane with a hole in it, or a cilinder. They all have non-contractible loops that may go around a certain region as many times as you wish. The fundamental group in this case is the group of integers under addition, $\mathbb{Z}$: if you follow a loop that goes around $n$ times and then another loop that goes around $m$ times, you have gone around $n+m$ times. Higher dimensional spheres $S^n$, $n>1$, however, only have contractible loops, so $\pi_1$ is the identity for all of them.

Next example would be a torus, $T^2=S^1\times S^1$. Now you have two independent directions you can loop around. Since loops in different directions commute, the total fundamental group is just the product of the $S_1$ groups, so the result is $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Basically you have pairs of integers where each member is the number of times you go around in each direction. The fundamental group of a product space $\pi_1(X\times Y)$ is always the direct product of the fundamental groups, $\pi_1(X)\times\pi_1(Y)$, if $X$ and $Y$ are path-connected. So if you consider $n$-dimensional tori, $T^n=(S^1)^n$, you get $\pi_1(T^n)=\mathbb{Z}^n$.

A less simple example would be the projective plane $\mathbb{R}P^2$, which is just a disk with diametrically opposed points on the boundary identified. Then you only have two types of loops, the ones that start and end at the same point and the ones that start at a point and end at the diametrically opposed point. There is no notion of going around anything, and $\pi_1$ in this case is just the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ group $\{-1,1\}$.

For more general cases it is usually not the case that we find a simple description of $\pi_1$. It is usually described by a set of generators and a set of conditions that these generators have to meet. The fundamental group of a closed and oriented surface of genus 2 (a sphere with two handles), for example, is the group with four generators, $\{a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2\}$  that satisfy the condition $[a_1,b_1]=[a_2,b_2]$, where $[a,b]=aba^{-1} b^{-1}$.  You can look up “van Kampen Theorem”.